# IntelliJ-idea может полноценно заменить собой Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

А разве IntelliJ-idea может полноценно заменить собой Android Studio?

Comment: как альтернатива да, но Вам придётся отдельно подтягивать вьюхи, прикручивать эмулятор и тд...

Comment: А если наоборот?

Comment: а если наоборот, то все нужные модули уже установлены из коробки (в Android Studio имеется ввиду)

Answer (score 3):

Да, может. Особенно если это Intellij IDEA Ultimate, правда придется кое-что допиливать вручную. Хотя в последних версиях Intellij IDEA - уже есть автоматические настройки/визарды для настройки Android разработки.

P.S. Для тех, кто совсем в танке, Android Studio это специализированная версия Intellij IDEA для Android разработки.